# Rails, select_tag: need both id and string returned in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a `select_tag` from data that is *not* from `active_record`.  In my controller, I prepare an array suitable for `options_for_select`:

```
@opts = @yap_response["businesses"].map { |bus| [bus["name"], bus["id"]] }
```

And in my view, I make a `select_tag`:

```
<%= select_tag(:restaurant_id, options_for_select(@opts, @party.restaurant.yap_id)) %>
```

This works fine, and I get the id of the selected item in the `params[:restaurant_id]` as excpected.  But I also need the string that was displayed in the drop down - in my case the name.  If this had come from `active_record`, I could just look it up in the database with the id, but it didn't.  And I no longer have the data I created earlier in the the other controller method.  How can I pass the selected *name* back in `params[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a clean way to do that. But here are some work-arounds:

**Option 1:** Encode both the id and the name in the value, then split them apart on the server with `params[:restaurant_id].split(':')`.

```
@opts = @yap_response["businesses"].map { |bus| [bus["name"], "#{bus['id']}:#{bus['name']}"] }
```

And the second argument in `options_for_select` will have to be "id:name", too.

**Option 2:** Add a hidden field, then use javascript to set its value to the selected name. But you're obviously out of luck if your users don't have javascript enabled.

**Option 3:** Add a hidden field filled with `@yap_response["business"].to_json`. Then `JSON.parse` it server-side and match the name with the id in `params`.

Comment: Option 1 is fine.  I tried something similar, putting both values in a hash, but you can't pass that through HTML.  Thanks.